# Pages 5.0 Language

Tags: pages, macos

On Mavericks, how can I change the language of text in the new version of Pages? They seem to have removed such an option.

Comment: excuse my dumbyness but where my the 'spelling and Grammar panel' be?

Comment: Under the Edit menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to set the language of any piece of text is gone.  Supposedly the app will now autodetect the language on a paragraph basis, but how well that actually works remains to be seen.  Otherwise, as pointed out already, it's the Spelling and Grammar route, which applies to the whole text.

Comment: I can't find a quote from Apple, but Pages now uses the system wide spell check, which includes an Automatic by Language option (within which you can check specific languages).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the language used for spell checking, you can change it from the Spelling and Grammar panel:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the language of check spelling:
http://help.apple.com/pages/mac/5.2/#/tanf3d8c3e49

You cannot change the language of the document (this concept is gone). I'm Brazilian and could only update the apps of Pages, Keynote and Numbers after changing my OS language from *Portuguese (Brazilian)* to *English*. I guess those apps are not ready for other languages as the time of this comment.

Comment: Glitches like you found in the update process are really irrelevant to the languages available in Pages for either spellcheck or in the menus and dialogues or keyboard input.