# How does one use different languages in Pages headers and footers?

Tags: macos, pages, iwork, language, spellcheck

[**EDIT**]  I'm afraid this language feature is [gone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106337/pages-5-0-language) in Pages 5.*

How does one use different languages in Pages headers and footers?
I don't need spell checking but language switching (for headers and footers in an automatic language different from the system language)

Google (and forums) says:
*"Inspector > Text > More > Language"* and create custom style.

But... I have no "language" tab in *Inspector -> Text -> More*

When I select text I see:

[image]

(In OS X/Preferences I already selected multiple languages for spell checking)

System: **El Capitan**
Pages: **5.6.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pages 5 can no longer tag text according to language, to have this feature you must go back to using Pages 4.   For spellcheck, you select the dictionary via Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar.

Answer (score 0):

- Highlight the section of page number
- Go to Document
- Section
- Format

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

I'm writing in Polish. In Pages version 5.6:

- Select all the text
- Go to **Edit > Spelling and Grammar**
- At the bottom of small window you may select your language.

Voila!

Comment: This answer just duplicates the previous one, and it's not even correct, because you can't see the dictionary unless you go a layer further down than Spelling and Grammar.